# sqlite3_unlock_notify

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, backend

I am building a class to work with sqlite3
Now it may happens that the database is getting locked cause I am working with many queries.
Now for that i want to use the mehotod
 **sqlite3_unlock_notify()**  like:

```
if (!strcmp(err, "database is locked")){
                if (sqlite3_unlock_notify(database, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    return [self perfomQuery:query Error:error];
            }
```

Now the problem is that i am getting a build red warning that says:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_unlock_notify", referenced from:...

Does anyone know what to do about it?
Just to make clear: I am using libsqlite3.0.dylib
10x

Comment: This is highly off-topic, but why do you reinvent the wheel instead of using something like FMDB?

Comment: Did u include the sqlite3.h file?

Answer (score 2):

I belive this could be happening because the optional flag SQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY was not included at the time of compiling sqlite3.

Please rechek your Makefile and check for this flag and include if its omitted.

You can refer http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_unlock_notify to understand more about this flag. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_unlock_notify` can be used only when multiple connections in the same process access the same database in shared-cache mode, which is useful only in multithreaded servers, so it has been left out of your SQLite configuration.

You should reorganize your app so that there is only a single database connection.

Comment: I used @synchronized, but according to apple documentation if 2 threads calling the same method with different arguments the method will be called parallel
Do you think the the next is good solution:
void *some_thread(void *arg) {
    sqlite3_mutex_enter(sqlite3_db_mutex(db));
    // Perform some queries on the database
    sqlite3_mutex_leave(sqlite3_db_mutex(db));
  }
?

Comment: But still, if i comes to database lock error I want to unlock it

Comment: Your `sqlite3_db_mutex` code is correct. You should not get lock errors if your app has only one connection if no other process is accessing the DB.